# Are there instances when a new term has been purposely introduced into the language and actually put to use?

Tags: word-usage

I am thinking of the suggested use of *ze* as an alternative for *he or she*. I cannot think of an example where such a thing has actually been adopted and put to general use.

Comment: From [Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gas): **gas** 1650s, from Dutch gas, probably from Greek khaos "empty space" (see chaos). The sound of Dutch "g" is roughly equivalent to that of Greek "kh." First used by Flemish chemist J.B. van Helmont (1577-1644), probably influenced by Paracelsus, who used khaos in an occult sense of "proper elements of spirits" or "ultra-rarified water," which was van Helmont's definition of gas. // David Crystal coined the term **lexeme** "A lexeme is a unit of lexical meaning, which exists regardless of any inflectional endings ...

Comment: it may have or the number of words it may contain. Thus, _fibrillate_, _rain cats and dogs_, and _come in_ are all lexemes" [ [Grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/lexemeterm.htm)]

Comment: Are there instances when a new term has been put to use *without* being purposely introduced?

Comment: The word [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) was invented pretty much out of thin air, and went on to achieve a degree of popularity.

Comment: In English _its_ (the neuter possessive pronoun -- the one without the apostrophe) is a novel introduction, replacing _his_, which was used for both masculine and neuter. Later, _you_ (a 2nd-person plural pronoun) was introduced for 2nd-person singular as well. But only because people decided individually to use them, not because they were official.

Comment: Individual words and phrases are constantly being created (neologisms). Dictionaries are always scrambling to keep up. Closed set words (like pronouns) and syntax however are hard to innovate deliberately. 'They' is more likely to catch on (again!) as a nongendered pronoun than 'ze' because borrowing is easier than a weird new word.

Answer (score 6):

New words, or neologisms, are almost always intentionally introduced and adopted into the English language. [Here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-s-new) are many that have recently been added to OxfordDictionaries.com, including *selfie stick, cryptocurrency,* and *binge-watch*. These words were not *accidentally* introduced to the English language, but rather done so for a purpose — namely, to allow us to speak of things as yet unnamed.

While *ze* has not yet been accepted by the mainstream, words like [*cisgender*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisgender) are in the process of becoming accepted and words like [*bikini*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikini) have been accepted. Every word, at one point in time, did not exist and was therefore created to fulfill a particular purpose; however, not every word created has gained widespread use.

If you are truly curious, I suggest looking up any word's [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/).

As a side note, this reminds me of the children's book [*Frindle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frindle), which is about what would happen if a child decided he was going to start calling pens *frindles.* That won't give you any answers, but it might be nice to read.

Answer (score 5):

[**Ms.**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ms.&searchmode=none) is probably the most obvious example.

> (plural Mses.), 1949, considered a blend of Miss and Mrs. - <sub><sup>Etymonline</sup></sub>

Prior to the feminist movement of the mid-1900s, women were either Miss (unmarried) or Mrs. (married, widowed, or divorced).  In contrast, men of adult age were always Mr., regardless of marital status.  It was felt that it was insulting to women to be so defined and characterized by marital status when men were not.  Ms. (pronounced "miz") was a manufactured alternative introduced.  At one time, its usage was considered a somewhat controversial feminist statement.  But by now it has largely replaced Miss and a significant number of married women use it, too.

Comment: In my experience, Ms has not replaced Miss. The two, and Mrs, seem to lead an uneasy co-existence.

Comment: @Anton - it has in the US. I've been married 30 years and have never used "Mrs." There's nothing uneasy about it.

Comment: +1 - a perfect example, and very much along the lines of the OP's "ze", but in this case, Miss and Mrs. (If no one has yet welcomed you to the site yet, Welcome! Glad you're here.)

Comment: This reminds me of Douglas Hofstadter's illustrative little piece "A person paper on purity in language". It discusses (and opposes) the recent introduction of race-neutral words in a hypothetical language that opposes not *he* and *she* but *whe* and *ble*. (Whites are addressed as *Master*. Blacks are addressed as *Nr* or *Niss* depending on whether they are employed or not.) For the humour impaired: The purpose of this piece is to illustrate how offensive the sexism of language actually is, and how ridiculous the arguments against *Ms.* are.

Comment: Thanks medica - this is a great website, and wonderful questions!  It is quite challenging answering some of them.

Comment: From medica's comment, It seems that Ms enjoys better currency in the US than in the UK. I merely report how things are in the UK. Medica merely reports how things are in the US. Here, we do not use Ms in professional life; indeed, few people even know how to pronounce it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. *Gay* comes to mind (from [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=gay&allowed_in_frame=0)):

> The "Dictionary of American Slang" reports that gay (adj.) was used by homosexuals, among themselves, in this sense since at least 1920. Rawson ["Wicked Words"] notes a male prostitute using gay in reference to male homosexuals (but also to female prostitutes) in London's notorious Cleveland Street Scandal of 1889. Ayto ["20th Century Words"] calls attention to the ambiguous use of the word in the 1868 song "The Gay Young Clerk in the Dry Goods Store," by U.S. female impersonator Will S. Hays, but the word evidently was not popularly felt in this sense by wider society until the 1950s at the earliest.

My understanding is that the gay community had had enough of having only derogatory or clinical terms to describe their sexual preference and chose to use a word that simply meant *happy*. The usage later percolated to the rest of society.

In technical writing, this phenomenon is very common. An author will publish a paper describing a novel process/moiety/species or whatever, and their chosen name for it is usually accepted by the rest of the scientific community. Off the top of my head, I can think of [*wobble position*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobble_base_pair) coined by Francis Crick. There are easily dozens of similar examples in science.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (1997) has this entry for the word *quiz*:

> **quiz.** A short test. The tale may be apocryphal, but it's said that in the late 18th century Dublin theater manager James Daley bet that he could invent and introduce a new meaningless word into the language almost overnight. He proceeded to pay Dublin urchins to chalk the word *quiz* on every wall in town. By morning almost all Dubliners had seen the word, and because no one new what it meant, the meaningless *quiz* became the word for a "test of knowledge."

It's an amusing story, but it has a chronological problem: according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) *quiz* first appeared in English in 1749—which is a bit early for a "late 18th century" theater manager to have dreamed it up. On the other hand, the earliest two definitions that the *Eleventh Collegiate* gives are "1 : an eccentric person" and "2 : PRACTICAL JOKE," both of which seem fairly relevant to the story that Hendrickson repeats. The Eleventh Collegiate contents itself with reporting *quiz*'s etymology as "origin unknown."

Of the Dublin story, Glynnis Chantrell, *The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories* (2002) rather sourly writes, "There is no evidence to support this theory." There is, however, a rather striking parallel mystery surrounding the word *quoz*. From Charles Mackay, [*Memoirs of Extraordinary Popular Delusions and the Madness of Crowds*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NmEOAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA240&dq=%22mackay%22+quoz&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIgJzWwJ_zxgIV1ymICh09pgS6#v=onepage&q=%22mackay%22%20quoz&f=false), volume 2 (1841):

> Many years ago the favourite phrase [in London] (for, though but a monosyllable, it was a phrase in itself) was **Quoz**. This odd word took the fancy of the multitude in an extraordinary degree, and very soon acquired an almost boundless meaning. When vulgar wit wished to mark its incredulity, and raise a laugh at the same time, there was no resource so sure as this popular piece of slang. When a man was asked a favour which he did not choose to grant, he marked his sense of the suitor's unparalleled presumption by exclaiming *Quoz!* When a mischievous urchin wished to annoy a passenger, and create mirth for his comrades, he looked him in the face, and cried out *Quoz!* ... Every alehouse resounded with *Quoz* ; every street-corner was noisy with it, and every wall foe miles around was chalked with it.
>
> But like all other earthly things, *Quoz* had it season, and passed away as suddenly as it arose, never again to be the pet and the idol of the populace.

So neither *quiz* nor *quoz* is a perfect example of a word devised and propagated for the amusement of its originator, and yet both have enough hints of such an origin to (if nothing else) support quite old popular stories to that effect.

---

On a more recent (and less fanciful) level it seems highly probable that *laser* as an acronym for "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation" was coined (in 1957) with the fully formed idea that it would serve as a new and handily simplified name for the technology.